Closed form for nested sum involving ratios of binomial coefficients
I ran into the following nested sum of binomial coefficients in my research, but I couldn't find the closed form expression for it. I looked at various sources and still couldn't find the answer. So I thought I should ask for help here!
Let's denote $Z_k(n) = \binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$.
$P_l$ is a nested sum of $Z_k$'s,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    P_{l}(n_0) &= \sum_{n_1=1}^{n_0} \sum_{n_2=1}^{n_1} \cdots \sum_{n_L=1}^{n_{L-1}} \frac{Z_{k-1}(n_{0}-n_{1})}{Z_k(n_{0})} \frac{Z_{k-1}(n_{1}-n_{2})}{Z_{k}(n_{1})}\cdots \frac{Z_{k-1}(n_{L-1}-n_{L})}{Z_k(n_{L-1})}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We can write down the recursion relation for $P_l$ from the above definition,
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        P_{l+1}(n)&= \sum_{m=1}^{n} P_l(m) \frac{Z_{k-1}(n-m)}{Z_k(n)}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
For example, for $L=1$, we have
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        P_1(n) = \frac{n}{n+k-1}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
For $L=2$, it starts to get complicated and involves hypergeometric function
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        P_2(n) = 1 - \frac{k-1}{n + k - 1} {}_3 F_2 (1, k-1, -nk, 2 - k - n; 1)
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Is there any hope for closed-form solution of $P_l(n)$ for general $n$ and $L$ (assuming that both $n$ and $L$ are positive integers)? Or some kind of simple asymtoptic form when $n \to \infty$? I will be satisfied even if we need to replace the sums with integrals, since the large $n$ limit is what I ultimately care for.
The closest related reference I can find is section 3 in https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL13/Butler/butler7.pdf, however it is not exactly what I am looking for. Please help, any thoughts would be much appreciated!
